# Can a sum of distinct power of three be expressed as half the sum of other distinct powers of 3?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Suppose I have an integer with a base $3$ expansion that contains only $1$s and $0$s. That is, the integer is the sum of distinct powers of three, where each power of three is added at most once. For example, $3^1 + 3^3 + 3^9$ or $3^1 + 3^2$. My question is that if I took half this integer, could this also be an integer with a base $3$ expansion that contains only $1$s or $0$s or can it also be expressed as sums of distinct powers of three.

Comment: Just go in the other direction, if $x$ has only $0$s and $1$s in its ternary expansion, then $2x$ has only $0$s and $2$s in its ternary expansion.

Comment: Play around with a couple of examples, and see if you can spot what exactly dividing by 2 does to the trits of a base 3 number with only 1s. It's pretty pretty.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Divide both sides by the least power of three involved and then see what happens if you take modulo 3